# How to add to inclusion rules to OpenCoverage?

Tags: code-coverage, opencover

I'd like to limit the coverage of my OpenCover process to something like this:

+[BaseName.NameSpace1.*]* +[BaseName.NameSpace2.*]*

and I'd hope see only those classes under BaseName.NameSpace1 and BaseName.NameSpace2 but in my attempts all I get are those under BaseName.NameSpace2. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks right assuming you have two assemblies.

The first part between the `[]` is the assembly (or module) filter and the second part is the namespace/class filter.

it could be that what you actually want is

```
+[*]BaseName.NameSpace1.* +[*]BaseName.NameSpace2.*
```

which would filter those namespaces regardless of the assembly

see the [Usage](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/wiki/Usage#understanding-filters) wiki entry for "Understanding Filters"